# Change panel property in GUI

Tags: user-interface, matlab, panel, visible

I tried many things and looked with thousant of keywords thru google and stackoverflow and I literally always fall on the very same (useless for me) solutions.

Here's my problem:

I have a GUI with a uibuttongroup "Youpi" with two radio buttons "visible" and "invi".
I have an other uipanel "Tralala" .

I create the following code:

```
function Youpi_SelectionChangeFcn(hObject,eventdata)
switch get(eventdata.NewValue,'Tag') % Get Tag of selected object.
    case 'visible'
        set(handles.Tralala, 'visible', 'on');
    case 'invi'
        set(handles.Tralala, 'visible', 'off');
    otherwise
        % Code for when there is no match.        
end
```

It does not work and I get always the same error message (see below). 
I made these two tests to figure out where the problem is from:
_I changed the case by a disp function : when I toggle my two radio buttons, the messages are displayed properly. It does not come from SelectionChangeFcn function.
_In the very first function, called "GUI_OpeningFcn" , I input `set(handles.Tralala, 'visible', 'off');` and it works properly (e.g. I don't see the panel if I run the GUI).

Do you know why the panel handle disappears from one function to an other ?

Here's the error message :

```
??? Undefined variable "Tralala" or class "handles.Tralala".

Error in ==> MaccorGUI>Youpi_SelectionChangeFcn at 272
        set(handles.Tralala, 'visible', 'on');

Error in ==> hgfeval at 63
        feval(fcn{1},varargin{:},fcn{2:end});

Error in ==> uitools.uibuttongroup.childAddedCbk>manageButtons at 80
    hgfeval(cbk, source, evdata);

??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

Please help me find a solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found the solution. I don't think it is the best one but at least it works.

Before "switch" i added the following command:

```
a = guidata(get(hObject,'parent'));
```

And in the switch instead of using "handles" I use "a".

note: it works also with guihandles ( you can have access to handles.output this way)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add *handles* to the selection change function definition

```
function Youpi_SelectionChangeFcn(hObject,eventdata, handles)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) . However I still get a similar error, only the first line changed:
`??? Input argument "handles" is undefined.`
It is a start for finding the solution. I'll keep you update if I find out.

Comment: I have R2010a . On the web I see there are people from 2006 for who the "handles" input appears automaticaly when making the callback SelectionChangeFcn . So I deleted my function to right-click on my button group and calback>> SelectionChangeFcn instead of doing it manualy. This time the "handles" input appears. however in the debugger I have only hObject and eventdata once I clicked on one of the radio button.

Comment: @Wlikotae: Strange not sure what is going on. Anyway, I see you found a work around.

Answer (score 0):

I created a group panel with a button each time I was one of the button selects an image he m'aficher each button has an image
thank you for helping me to find the source code
I'm doing it
uipanel4_SelectionChangeFcn function (hObject, EVENTDATA, handles)
% hObject handle To The selected object in uipanel4
% With The followings EVENTDATA structure fields (see UIBUTTONGROUP)
% EventName: string 'SelectionChanged' (read only)
% OldValue: handle Of The Previously selected object or empty if none selected WAS
% NewValue: handle Of The Currently selected object
% handles structure with handle and user data (see GUIDAT)
if RadioButton1 == get (handles.radiobutton1, 'value', 1)
      Set (handles.axes4, 'because')
  else radioButton2 == get (handles.radiobutton2, 'value', 1)
Set (handles.axes4 'man')